# Derivate of $e^{-x\cdot x}$ with Hermite polynomials.

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, hermite-polynomials

Define the Hermite polynomial $H_n$ by
$$H_n=(-1)^n e^{x^2}\frac{d^2 e^{-x^2}}{dx^n}.$$

Now let $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$, $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}_0^d$ be a multi-index and 
$\partial^\alpha=\frac{\partial^{\alpha_1}}{\partial x^{\alpha_1}}...\frac{\partial^{\alpha_d}}{\partial x^{\alpha_d}}$.

Now I have to show that
$$\partial^\alpha e^{-x\cdot x}=(-1)^{|\alpha|}\prod_{j=1}^d H_{\alpha_j}(x_j)e^{-x\cdot x}$$

Honestly I dont really know how to start, so help is very much appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from the simple factorization property
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y} f(x)g(y)=f'(x)g'(y)\ .
$$

Comment: So it just looked that scary :D Thank you very much!